# How do I include Javascript inside PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to write some Javascript inside PHP, I made a simple button that takes you to the previous page. The button is showing but the functionality of the button isn't working.
This is the code I have.

```
<?php
$product;
if (empty($product))
{
    echo
    '
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        header("location:".history.go(-1));
    }
    </script>
    <button onclick=myFunction()>Click me</button>
    ';
    exit();


}
```

I go to my local server to the file where this code is and except it to work but it doesn't. For example, I go to `http://127.0.0.1/test1.php` where there is is a button (which works perfectly) that takes you to `http://127.0.0.1/test2.php` (where this this piece of code is). When I press the 'Click me' button, nothing happens. I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong? Or is it because It's local that the problems are caused? I've tried this in Chrome and Safari.

Comment: You are mixing PHP and JavaScript. They are two completely different languages.

Comment: @Dharman You're completely right! Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Check MDN article for [`Window.history`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history). Take note of `history.back()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong code history:

```
function myFunction() {
    window.history.go(-1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved my answer. I was indeed mixing stuff as @Dharman said but your code solves my issue perfectly!